# Can we rotate a 3-d png file that is ouput by gnuplot?

Tags: plot, rotation, gnuplot

So, when we do something like: 'splot sin(x)*cos(y)' and we can rotate the ouput.

But if we do: 
'set terminal png'

'set output "a.png"'

'splot sin(x)*cos(y)'

Then, is it possible to rotate the "a.png" file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot rotate a png file as if you were in interactive mode.

To display a 3D data set on a flat screen, any program must calculate a 2D projection in order to show the data. This projection is then [rasterized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation), i.e. converted to pixels in order to be saved as png.

Already with the projection you loose all 3D information which would be necessary to perform any kind of 3D manipulation, besides that png looses even more information by the rasterization.

Gnuplot doesn't support any special data format which would be necessary to manipulate the 3D view later with a viewer.